# WinSock Have Error #10060: Vagrant+VirtualBoxで立ち上げたUbuntuに外部からアクセスできません。

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

仮想環境をVagrant+VirtualBoxで立ち上げ、そこに簡単なWebサービスを試しに展開してみようと思っています。Vagrantを起動後、ローカルのPCから下図の設定でアクセス出来る事は確認できました。
[image: RLoginのServer Edit Entry設定。ローカルでアクセスに成功したのと同じSSH認証鍵を利用]

同じ設定で外部PCからアクセスした所、以下の様なエラーが出てしまったのですが、外部からアクセスする場合追加で設定が必要なのでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみにVagrantのSSHの設定は以下の通りでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記：
(1)頂いたアドバイスを基に調べて見た所、ポートフォワーディングを行えば良さそうだと判断し、Vagrantfileで以下の設定を付け加えた後に再起動した時に表示された結果を添付します。

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

(2)[Qiitaの記事](https://qiita.com/_norin_/items/8f534bd0531a960af5e9)を参考にポートに同じネットワーク内のPCからアクセス出来るかをPowerShellで調べてみた所、問題は無さそうでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

ローカルPCからゲストOSへの接続時、ポート番号に`2222`を指定されていますが、こちらはゲストOS側でsshの待ち受けポートを変更していますか？それともポートフォワーディングを使用されているのでしょうか。

どちらにせよ、まずは「外部PCからローカルPC」に対して`2222`ポートへの接続が通るかを確認してみてください(ローカルPCでのファイアウォール設定等)。

併せて、ゲストOSがどんなネットワーク設定になっているかも質問に追記してもらうと、より具体的な回答がつけやすいと思います。例えば「ホストオンリーアダプタ」を使用している場合には、ローカルPCとゲストOS間でしか通信ができません。

参考： [Vagrantのネットワーク周りのあれこれ](http://labs.septeni.co.jp/entry/20140707/1404670069)

Comment: 参考に頂いたリンク先の情報から、ポートフォワーディングの設定を行えば良さそうだと判断し、その設定後にreloadして表示された結果を質問欄にアップしました。ファイアウォール設定を確認してポート8080を使える様にしたのですが、残念ながらこれでも外部からのアクセスは出来ませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

まずはVirtualBoxのネットワークをブリッジにしましょう
そうするとホストのネットワークにゲストが直接接続される形となりますんで、それで接続できるのを目指しましょう

それができてから、ネットワークをNATなりホストオンリなりに（必要があるなら）変えていくのがよろしいかと